# Numpy / Why can't I use reshape with random.randint?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this line od code :

```
tirage2=np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10,5))
```

[image]

So I was thinking using reshape is possible like in this line :

```
tirage4=np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
```

[image]

But this throws an error :

```
tirage3=np.random.randint(0,2).reshape(5,10)
```

**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'reshape'**

Comment: Have you read the docs for `numpy.random.randint`? Check what inputs it takes.

Comment: You're calling `.reshape()` after `.randint()` thereby trying to reshape an integer. you need to use `np.random.randint()` with the `size` kwarg

Comment: Compare `np.arange(50)` and `np.randint(0,2)`.  Are they the same `type`?  Same `shape`?  `reshape(5,10)` only works with an array with shape `(50,)` (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `np.random.randint(a,b)`, it returns an `int` object between `a` and `b`. If you want a matrix with values in that range, you should use `np.random.randint(a, b, size=(rows,cols))`. Then you'll be able to call `reshape` on the resulting `np.ndarray`.

The reason you can call `reshape` on the return type of `np.arange` is because `np.arange` returns an `np.ndarray`, which can be reshaped.

Comment: yes sorry, I should have use Type to understand the problem